# Find the ways to add numbers up to K value which there are multiple K to satisfy

Tags: arrays, sorting, hashmap, dynamic-programming

I have encountered this problem during my preparation for the interview, I can't think of an elegant way to solve it:

Given an array of positive integers and target K, asking what are the combinations can satisfy K? We assume `all integers <= K`

example:

```
given: [5,4,3,5,2,1,4,8,10]
K = 10

10
5+5 = 10
2+8 = 10
4+4+1 = 9
3 *because it can't be add to any conbination and still less than or equal to k

so one of the answers is [10],[5,5],[2,8],[4,4,1],[3]
but we want minimum numbers of combination, in this case, we get 5
```

My apology on the tags, I don't know which is the best way to solve it and I have to add tags to post the question

Comment: Can you please provide the full problem statement?